# inheritance Problems with undefined types

Tags: c#, class, types, constructor, multiple-constructors

I want to be able to create a constructor that can call on its types but without any constraints.

```
public class Box
{
    public class Command
    {
        public string name;
        public string num;

        public Object PARAMS { get; set; }//<--- HERE
    }
}
```

I want `PARAMS` to be an undefined type that could possibly call one of these other classes

```
public class Person:Box
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
 public class Item:Box
 {
     public string ItemName { get; set; }
     public string Info { get; set; }
 }
```

How can I define `PARAMS`? I am trying inheritance, but I am not so sure on how to call on other classes.

Comment: Type it as `Box`.   Am I missing something?

Comment: @Servy, probably the nested class is unnecessary, but yes having `PARAMS` as `Box` would work.

Comment: @Habib, the nested class is unnecessary, but I am trying out Xml Serializer, and I have a set format based on this structure.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options - either set it's type as a `Box`, or make it generic:

```
public class Command<T> where T : Box
{
    public string name;
    public string num;

    public T PARAMS { get; set; }
}
```

Or:

```
public class Command
{
    public string name;
    public string num;

    public Box PARAMS { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was not sure if I could define it as 'Box' when trying to reach 'Person'

Comment: @albertSilva You can, but you'll only (directly) have access to the properties and methods defined on `Box`.  Making them virtual can often solve the issues.