# xml serialization with a generic aproach for elements.

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize code so the result can look like this.

```
<BOX>
    <COMMAND name= "Person">
        <PARAMS>
            <NAME>TOM</NAME>
            <LASTNAME>MILL</LASTNAME>
        </PARAMS>
    </COMMAND>
<PIN> 000000 </PIN>
</BOX>
```

but the result can also be

```
<BOX>
    <COMMAND name= "Item">
        <PARAMS>
            <ITEM>TOY</ITEM>
            <PRICE>MILL</PRICE>
            <NUM>111</NUM>
        </PARAMS>
    </COMMAND>
<PIN> 000000 </PIN>
</BOX>
```

One of the thing that changes is the `<PARAMS>` element. I want to create a class structure that can be "recycled"

```
public class Box
{
    public class Command
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string name;

        public Object PARAMS { get; set; }//<--- HERE
    }
}
```

I want `PARAMS` to be an undefined type that could possibly call one of these other classes

```
public class Person:Box
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
 public class Item:Box
 {
     public string ItemName { get; set; }
     public string Info { get; set; }
 }
```

This is my code

```
BOX AddPerson = new BOX ();
Person person1 = new Person();
BOX.Command hey = new BOX.Command();

AddPerson.PIN= "000000";
hey.name = "AddPerson";

person1.FirstName = "TOM";
person1.LastName = "MILL";

hey.PARAMS = person1; //<<--THIS PART I want to be able to assign Person or Item

AddPerson.COMMAND = hey;

Console.WriteLine();
Console.ReadLine();
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, AddPerson);
Console.WriteLine(textWriter.ToString());
```

I want to see if there is a better way to implement this idea.

Comment: Remember that time you already asked this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324626/inheritance-problems-with-undefined-types

Comment: @Preston Guillot I am new to stackoverflow, and I guess I should delete the other question. but this one has to do with serialization. I am looking for an answer dealing with the XML serialization Library.